# How to pass a specific button id to a jquery click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have couple of buttons in a table row of a table that I am generating dynamically. Now, each of these buttons will have their own functionality. So, I would like to understand when I click on a button in a row, how do I pass that specific button id to the onclick event of the table row.

```
 $('#demotbl').DataTable( {
      "aaData": data,
      "aoColumns": [
          { "sTitle": "PrescriptionId" },
          { "sTitle": "PatientNumber" },
          { "sTitle": "PatientName" },
          { "sTitle": "Address" },
          { "sTitle": "PhoneNumber" },
          { "sTitle": "Prescription" },
          { "sTitle": "Date" },
          {
              "targets": -1,
              "data": null,
              "defaultContent": "<input type='submit' id ='btn2' name='btn2' value='view' />"
          },
           {
              "targets": -2,
              "data": null,
              "defaultContent": "<input type='file' class='cloudinary-fileupload' data-cloudinary-field= 'image_id' />"
          },
           {
              "targets": -3,
              "data": null,
              "defaultContent": "<input type='submit' id='btn' name='btn' value="btn" />"
          }




      ]

    })


                    var table = $('#demotbl').DataTable();



     $('#demotbl tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('selected')
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var rows = table.row(tr);

        var info = rows.data();
        var dat = [info];
        var patient_info = info[1];

        console.log( "patientinfo",info);
      // demoFromHTML(dat)






    } );
```

In the above code, I am passing the button in the on click event, how do i  pass button ids?

Comment: if I understand correctly you can access id if you use `$(this).attr('id')` and if you want to add click event only to specific button id then `.on('click', 'button#id1, button#id2, button#id3', function(e) {`

Comment: Please correct your code '<input type='submit' id ='btn2' name='btn2' value='view'></button>' change it into '<input type='submit' id ='btn2' name='btn2' value='view'/>'  or '<button id ='btn2' name='btn2' value='view'></button>'

Comment: jassy  did you checked the answer???

Answer (score 3):

1. Declare same class name for every button
2. trigger click () event using class name
3. get id using **.attr()**

**example:**

```
<input type='submit' class='btn' id ='btn1' value='view'/>
<input type='submit' class='btn' id ='btn2' value='view'/>
```

and

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('id');
})
```

Comment: Hi @swathi_sri simply super

Comment: keep go on rocking